# Analog readings vary by higher current draw

Tags: voltage, batteries, analog, atmega

I have a circuit, where an Atmega328pb and an WS2812-LED-Strip is powered by a 3,7V battery which voltage is boosted by a step up converter to 5,1V.

To indicate low battery, It reads the unboosted battery voltage (Analog Pin directly connected to positive of battery) and blinks if the voltage is below my threshold and shuts down at a lower threshold.

Now I connect a lab bench power supply instead of a battery and set the voltage to my threshold (max current is set to more then enough), to simulate low battery. It works as expected, until I increase the brightness of the LED-Strip. Now it just shuts down like the voltage is 100 or even 300mV lower. The same sees the battery protection in my circuit and cuts power at full brightness even if the supply voltage is 300mV above the threshold.

I know that voltage drops if the resistance is too high for the supply, but the power supply still shows the correct voltage and the amps are far away from the max current I set.

I couldn't test it with a battery for now, but I think it'll be the same.

My question is, how to solve this problem. Can I somehow still get accurate readings? Or is there a software trick to do this?

Comment: There may be a switching ripple (caused by the boost converter) at battery side. And your ADC may catch that ripple's walley. You should've put an appropriate capacitor at that side. Plus, schematic, layout and oscillograms are needed.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend connecting the ADC input directly to the battery in case there is a situation where the boosted supply is shut down. There will be excessive current into the pin. A resistor plus a capacitor to create a filter as suggested by @Rohat will address both issues.

Comment: When the booster shuts down, the battery voltage just goes unboosted through the schottky diode. 
I understood that I just try to add a big decopling capacitor. How do I connect the resistor you mean?